# Rounding to a set of values in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a set of data which I want to round to a given set of values:

Example:
the set values is : 10000,5000,2500,2000,1000,500,250,200,100,50,25,20,10,5,2,1

I want to round to the nearest value (and not up/down round).
In case that the value is in the middle - to one of the options (don't care which).

26 -> 25
3.5 -> 2 or 5

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Array in `A1:A16` and you want to match the nearest for `C1`, you can use this *Array formula*

```
D1:
=INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(MIN(ABS($A$1:$A$16-C1)),ABS($A$1:$A$16-C1),0))

Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

Copy and paste down along column D to match values in column C.

[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion with no luck. 
what went wrong?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AgqeY_JYlfNHpoZVR1YW1PTk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @motilaluom You did not use it as an *Array Formula*. You should edit it and then press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by vlookup

Build a table

```
       |      A |      B
-------+--------+--------
     1 |      0 |      1
     2 |      1 |      2
     3 |      2 |      5
     4 |      5 |     10
     5 |     10 |     20
     6 |     20 |     25
     7 |     25 |     50
     8 |     50 |    100
     9 |    100 |    200
    10 |    200 |    250
    11 |    250 |    500
    12 |    500 |   1000
    13 |   1000 |   2000
    14 |   2000 |   2500
    15 |   2500 |   5000
    16 |   5000 |  10000

A20: 320
B20: =VLOOKUP(320,$A$1:$B$16,1,TRUE) --> 250
C20: =VLOOKUP(320,$A$1:$B$16,2,TRUE) --> 500
D20: =(B20+C20)/2 --> 375
E20: =IF(A20 < D20;B20;C20)
```

in E20 you will find your result

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED

I doubt an array formula is required, though assuming series is in A1 to A16 (sorted descending) following will return `#N/A` for numbers over `1000` and `0` for those less than `1` in C1:

```
 =IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1,A:A,-1))-C1<C1-INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1,A:A,-1)+1),INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1,A:A,-1)),INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C1,A:A,-1)+1))
```